# Fix view in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

I have to generate multiple maps for weeks out of QGIS. The view section has to be always the same and I will have to switch off my computer for time to time.

Is there a way to fix to a certain map section so I can just click somewhere whenever I need to generate a map?

Comment: Map items may be locked to showing the same layers and layer styles regardless of how you change your map window. You simply mustn't move the extent of that one layout.

Comment: Have you tried using a bookmark?